# How to optimize trading algorithm for most efficient speed

Tags: c++, algorithm

Suppose you want to implement an algorithm that works in the following way:

You read in from a file that contains values of the form:

```
Mark Buy  20 1 100
Bob  Sell 20 2 90
```

Where the input takes the form:

`<name><buy or sell><quantity><time><company><buy maximum or sell minimum>`

What's the fastest way to match buyers and sellers (for some company, where buyers and sellers are matched only if the person with the highest buy for that company is greater than the person with the lowest sell for that company).  The buy or sell that is top-most will be the one that determines what price to use.

So in the example given we'd have "Mark, at time 1, bought 20 of Google for $100 from Bob, at time 2."

How can we optimize this algorithm for speed?  Would reading in the entire file first be an optimal solution?

Comment: So, where's the trading algorithm? :)

Comment: Black box optimization. So thrilling :)

Comment: Any help would be great!

Comment: You get out a profiler and see where it's slow.

Comment: Seems like you'd have to read the entire file in order to be sure that you have all the data. I suppose you could load a chunk, look for a match, fail, load the next chunk, etc. Seems like it'd be simpler logic to just load the whole darned file and go from there.

Comment: How can I make sure executions occur in order (according to the input file), though?  If I read in the entire file and use, say, priority queues to maintain max buy and min sell, then I'll matching max and min for the entire file.

Comment: Yes, if there is no constraint on the start times of a file entry, you will need to read in the entire file first -- not for optimality, but for correctness.

Comment: I will also pile on and mention that it doesn't sound like you have an algorithm yet -- so technically you are *looking* for an algorithm, not optimizing one 8^)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is two [priority queues](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue) per commodity:  one for active buy bids (prioritized on max-price), and one for active sell bids (prioritized on min-price), plus an overall queue for bid creation/expiry events (prioritized on time).  (If your bids are in a batch file as described, rather than a causal/online sequence, you can just sort the creation/expiry events, but you still need the buy and sell queues)

Using priority queues is the crux; everything after that is plumbing:

```
foreach bid creation/expiry event, in chronological order:
  if the event is an expiry:
    delete the bid from the appropriate queue
  else, the event is a creation:
    add the bid to the appropriate queue
    repeat until no further transaction can be performed:
      find max-active-buy and min-active-sell bids for the given commodity
      if they match:
        execute (and record) the transaction
        update partially fulfilled bids, and remove completely fulfilled ones
```

When performing as a batch operation, you could simplify things a bit by sorting out each individual commodity, and executing each one separately.  However, this will not work if the markets interact in any way (such as checking for sufficient account balance).

---

Priority queue operations can have asymptotic performance of O(log N) in the number of items.  There are many fast, practical priority queue datastructures available which achieve this asymptotic limit.

Since you are evaluating an entire file as a batch, you may want to look into priority queues with amortized performance guarantees -- but if you expect to use your code in a real-time setting, you should probably stick to priority queues with strict per-query guarantees.

Comment: Priority queues aren't the most efficient for this job because they perform multiple sells followed by a big buy, or multiple buys followed by a big sell in O(nlogn) complexity.  For example, suppose 100, 1 quantity sells were placed and then 1, 100 quantity buy is placed.  If we're using priority queues, we have to delete the top and then readjust which, for all n sells will take O(nlogn) time.

Comment: The idea is that this operation can be done in O(n) time, I believe.  I'm just not sure how.

Comment: In general, you can't do better than O(log N) per element, because if you are fulfilling N orders with different prices, you need to sort them to determine which must be fulfilled first and that can't be done in less then O(N log N).  However, if multiple bids with the same price are a common case, you can aggregate identically-priced bids into the same priority-queue entry, which should improve the cost of handling K same-price bids to something like O(K + log N) where N is the number of *distinct prices* in the queue.

Comment: OK, also, if you have a limited number of prices available, you can perform a radix sort in O(L N) where L is the number of bits it takes to store a price.  There may be some way to take advantage of this as well, but I would start with a search for priority queues specialized for such limited-size keys...